# отключение ssh клиента без задержки

Tags: windows, ssh, putty

На предыдущем **vds** `putty` и `winscp` после команды `reboot` моментально выдавали окошко потерянного подключения, на новом сервере все просто подвисает до конца таймаута. 
Хостинг один, ОС одна (Debian 8).
Переподключаться стало менее удобно, подскажите как настроить "по старому".

Comment: просто к сведению: объяснение такому поведению (на английском) — http://serverfault.com/a/283162/292034

Comment: поискать настройки в sshd, чтобы при получении SIGTERM посылал разрыв соединения? Хотя сам поискал и не нашел, запросил на интерес: http://serverfault.com/questions/706475/force-disconnect-all-open-ssh-sessions-if-sshd-is-being-terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вольный перевод [ответа](https://serverfault.com/a/706494/292034) к аналогичному [вопросу](https://serverfault.com/q/706475/292034) (английский  текст присутствует как *html-комментарии*):

когда вы выключаете или перезагружаете систему, `systemd` пытается остановить все сервисы так быстро, как сможет. это приводит к тому, что отключается сеть и завершаются все выполняющиеся процессы — обычно в таком порядке. и когда `systemd` «убивает» «дочерние» *ssh-процессы*, которые обслуживают вашу *ssh-сессию*, сеть уже отключена и эти процессы не могут корректно завершить клиентское соединение.

первой мыслью может быть просто «убийство» *ssh-процессов* в качестве первого шага при выключении, и есть несколько «сервисных» файлов в конфигурации `systemd`, которые идут именно этим путём.

но есть, конечно, и более «тонкое» решение (как это и «предполагалось» делать): `systemd-logind`.

`systemd-logind` отслеживает активные сессии (локальные и через *ssh*) и назначает всем процессам, порождённым этими сессиями, так называемые «срезы» ("slices"). потому, когда система завершает работу, `systemd` может послать сигнал `SIGTERM` всем процессам внутри пользовательских «срезов» (которые включают и «дочерние» *ssh-процессы*, обслуживающие данную сессию), а затем продолжить отключение сервисов и сети.

`systemd-logind` требуется *pam-модуль* для того, чтобы получать уведомления о новых пользовательских сессиях, и ещё нужен `dbus` для того, чтобы `loginctl` мог проверить их статус, поэтому установите их оба:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpam-systemd dbus
```

---

комментарий от меня лично: ещё раз убеждаюсь в том, что `systemd` — это явно не та сторона в «борьбе добра со злом», которую я согласен выбрать и поддерживать.

Comment: Я этот вопрос задавал, ради того, чтобы почитать, что умные люди пишут. Спасибо за перевод ответа.